# How do I cache a video for offline playing?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://122.165.71.249:6060/test/music/killbill.mp3"];
// Setup the player
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:nil];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
```

I am using this code play online connection ,but i want offline also play in the video url link.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use an NSURLConnection to download the file yourself, you can then use the original URL for the movie player whilst downloading the video at the same time. When I did this I tried to get the video player to use the local file before I has finished, by delaying start of playback after a certain number of bytes have been received, but I found it would only work on the simulator but not on the actually iPhone/iPodTouch. If you do search for (MPMoviePlayerViewController "Nathan Day" Cache) you will see some example code I post on Apples Cocoa mailing trying to solve this.

Comment: i am solved this problem ,i am save mp3 file in to document directory path,thank u for response